# How to encrypt a text so that the length of the output is not more than 100 characters in java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt texts (usually with variable length) using Java, but I need to limit the character length of encrypted output since I have to send this encrypted text to an API which has this limitation (it does not save from the 101th char onwards). I see `AES256` is a secure algorithm and the JAVA code is [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-security/aes-256-encryption-decryption/), however even `TripleDES` produces longer than 100 character encrypted output (of course, for my inputs which are longer texts). I know it sounds awkward to expect a safe encryption algorithm to create a short-length encrypted text(at least not longer than the original text), but any idea about how I can solve my problem would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The length of the output is a function of the length of the input, its compressability, as well as any special encodings that are needed. If your plaintext is 300 characters it's going to be very difficult, even with compression, to achieve a 100 character output.

Comment: Thank you James, Do you mean that if I limit my plain text less than 300 characters I can resolve it? if yes, how?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean, 300 was just an example. I'm saying you should add more details about the plaintext, like what the longest plaintext is, and so forth.

Comment: There might be the address in different languages (and maybe including special characters for example in French or Italian  "Eugène" ), concatenating other strings like different Codes.  for sure they would be longer than 100 chars. what would be the maximum I really cannot guess

Answer (score 2):

Encryption is not a magic compression algorithm. Modern ciphers actually don't compress at all. A symmetric cipher in a mode of operation generally encrypts 1:1 with some overhead for e.g. the IV or authentication tag.

There are some things you can do:

1. Make sure you use the most efficient encoding and compression algorithms *before* encrypting;
2. Make sure that you minimize the overhead of the cipher (i.e. anything that is not 1:1 encryption);
3. Make sure that you use all the characters of the alphabet that are used for the storage solution (there is a lot of difference in being able to store 100 UTF-8 characters compared to US-ASCII characters, maybe non-printable characters can also be stored);
4. Use multiple text messages on the storage for a single encrypted message.

Good luck with your 100 character protocol.

Comment: Thanks a million and the 100 char protocol is what Google Analytics 4 (GA4) is presenting for custom dimensions. As long as we cannot compete with google, we should obey their rules :D

Comment: As long as it is understood that I'm not advocating to go around any restrictions of particular services.